# How to give client an option to print a receipt directly from the CodeIgniter website

Tags: php, codeigniter, printing, webclient

I need to give client to a print a receipt through my website directly. I know we can not do it via php because it is a serverside language. I have tried do it by using WebClientPrint.php. But I was unable to implement it. I need to know is it possible to implement such option in CodeIgniter

Comment: are you trying to print webpage? or some file pdf?

Comment: @ VK321 I need to print a pdf

Comment: Your question on hold. Edit question to make more clear to what you tried. Where is problem etc. So we can answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use js for printing:

```
var w = window.open('files/invoices/invoice.html','name','width=800,height=500');
w.onload = w.print;
w.focus();
```

If you need to generate the file then use ajax to do that & then use the file path to print using above js functions.

Comment: Thank you. It is seems like do my work

Comment: there is a problem of printing the file. It does the saving file with printing. Isn't there a way to prevent saving the file?

Comment: And also the content is missing in printed file and content is their in downloaded file

Comment: Plz follow the edits n try.

Comment: I need it the other way. This only save the file. I need it to be printed

Comment: The file has to be there & then when we call window.open(), it opens the file.
Once it loads completely (w.onload) then it calls print function(w.print).
Is the code not prompting the print window? if so then plz do check some browsers block the popup. 
And one more thing we can't give print unless we save the file first.